# How can if resolve this conflict between matrix keypad library and neopixel library?

Tags: library, neopixel, keypad

I'm trying to use a 4x3 matrix keypad as a user interface to control parameters of a Neopixel strip control program.

I'm using [Adafruit's Neopixel library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_NeoPixel) and [This Keypad library](https://github.com/Chris--A/Keypad).
Both work fine on their own and none of my code, outside this instantiation of the keypad library, interferes with the programs functionality.

<strike>The code is around 400 lines so I'm only including a snippet:</strike>
I've now included all functions which are called in setup, as well as the one we are supposed to land on in loop() as a result of the switch statement.

```
#include "math.h"
#include "Adafruit_NeoPixel.h"
#include "Keypad.h"
#ifdef __AVR__
#include "avr/power.h"
#endif

#define PIN 9 //Neopixel data pin
#define NUMPIXELS 300 //currently 300

const byte ROWS = 4; //four rows
const byte COLS = 3; //three columns
char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
    {'1','2','3'},
    {'4','5','6'},
    {'7','8','9'},
    {'*','0','#'}
};

byte rowPins[ROWS] = {8, 7, 6, 5}; //connect to the row pinouts of the keypad
byte colPins[COLS] = {4, 3, 2}; //connect to the column pinouts of the keypad

Keypad keypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS );

Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(NUMPIXELS, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

//f=1/p period should be between 1s and 10s so...
//frequencies should be somewhere between 0.1Hz and 1Hz
int period[NUMPIXELS];

float twoPI = 2 * PI;

int rainbowNow = 0;
unsigned int xOff = 0;

int switcha = 0;

byte hue = 192;
float sat = 0;
float lum = 1;

float lumSave;

int *rgb;

char select = '5';
char hueInc = '6';
char hueDec = '4';
char lumInc = '2';
char lumDec = '8';
char satInc = '3';
char satDec = '1';
char onoff = '0';

boolean holdFlag = 0;

void setup(void) {
  //create array of period lengths for each pixels sine wave
  randomSeed(10);
  for (int i = 0; i < NUMPIXELS; i++) {
    period[i] = random(2, 20);
  }
  Serial.begin(9600);

  strip.begin();
  strip.show(); // Initialize all pixels to 'off'

  //showOff();
  fadeIn();
  sparkle();
}

void loop(void) {

  char key = keypad.getKey();  
  change(key);

  switch(switcha) {
    case 0: solidColour(); break;
    case 1: rainbow(); break;
    case 2: twinkle(); break;
    case 3: satSine(); break;
    case 4: hueSine(); break;
    case 5: rainbowCycle(); break;
  }
}

void solidColour() {
  rgb = Wheel(hue, sat, lum);
  for(int i=0; i<strip.numPixels(); i++) {
    strip.setPixelColor(i, strip.Color(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]));
  }
  strip.show();
  delay(20);
}

void fadeIn() {
  Serial.println("FADE IN");
  for(float j=0; j<1; j+=0.16) {
    rgb = Wheel(hue, sat, j);
    for(int i=0; i<NUMPIXELS; i++) {
      strip.setPixelColor(i, strip.Color(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]));
    }
    strip.show();
    delay(100);
  }
}

void sparkle() {
  Serial.println("SPARKLE");
  rgb = Wheel(hue, sat, lum);
  strip.setPixelColor(0, strip.Color(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]));
  for(int i=1; i<NUMPIXELS; i++) {
    int blnk = random(0, NUMPIXELS-1);
    strip.setPixelColor(blnk, strip.Color(0, 0, 0));
    strip.show();
    delay(40);
    strip.setPixelColor(blnk, strip.Color(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]));
    strip.show();
  }
}

//will create pseudo-Saturation by reducing white with increasing sat
//brightness will be achieved by scaling all by a constant
// Input a value 0 to 255 to get a color value.
// The colours are a transition r - g - b - back to r.
int* Wheel(byte WheelPos, float pseudoSat, float pseudoLum) {
  static int rgb[3];
  WheelPos = 255 - WheelPos;
  if (WheelPos < 85) {
    rgb[0] = (255 - WheelPos * 3) * pseudoLum;
    rgb[1] = 0;
    rgb[2] = (WheelPos * 3) * pseudoLum;
  } else if (WheelPos < 170) {
    WheelPos -= 85;
    rgb[0] = 0;
    rgb[1] = (WheelPos * 3) * pseudoLum;
    rgb[2] = (255 - WheelPos * 3) * pseudoLum;
  } else if(WheelPos >= 170) {
    WheelPos -= 170;
    rgb[0] = (WheelPos * 3) * pseudoLum;
    rgb[1] = (255 - WheelPos * 3) * pseudoLum;
    rgb[2] = 0;
  }

  return rgb;
}

void change(char key) {
  if(key == select) { //select
    if(switcha < 5) {
      switcha++;
    } else {
      switcha = 0;
    }
  } else if(key == hueDec) { //fwd
    if(hue > 0) {
      hue--;
    } else {
      hue = 255;
    }
  } else if(key == hueInc) { //back
    if(hue < 255) {
      hue++;
    } else {
      hue = 0;
    }
  } else if(key == lumInc) { //up
    if(lum < 1) {
      lum+=0.05;
    } else {
      lum = 0.05;
    }
  } else if(key == lumDec) { //down
    if(lum > 0.05) {
      lum-=0.05;
    } else {
      lum = 1;
    }
  } else if(key == onoff) {
    if(lum != 0) {
      lumSave = lum;
      lum = 0;
    } else if(lum == 0) {
      lum = lumSave;
    }
   } else if(key == satInc) { //play
    if(sat < 1) {
      sat+=0.025;
    } else {
      sat = 0.025;
    }
  } else if(key == satDec) {
    if(sat > 0.025) {
      sat-=0.025;
    } else {
      sat = 1;
    }
  }
}
```

So long as I comment out the line `Keypad keypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS );`, the code runs as expected and the Neopixel strip lights up in the way I have programmed.
However, with that line, nothing lights up at all. The code still reaches all the functions, (I have checked with Serial.print).

(EDIT: It also works with the `Keypad keypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS );` included so long as I comment out the switch statement in loop(). How can a statement in loop affect the setup function?!)

I think it must have something to do with either interrupts, or a polling frequency within the Keypad library with interferes with the 'delicate' timing of the Neopixels.

The massively frustrating this is that I have solved this problem before on this exact hardware but the code was lost and I'm having to reconstruct it for a repair job.

If you could help me specifically identify the problem, or suggest how I might implement my keypad interface with the neopixels I would be very grateful.

Arduino ide2:1.0.5 (EDIT: also used 1.8.9 with no different result)

Arduino Nano Board

Sodial 4x3 Matrix Keypad

ws2812b rgb 300 neopixel 5M strip

Comment: Are you saying IDE version 1.0.5? That is ancient. Upgrade to something current.  I think 1.8.9 is the latest.  www.arduino.cc

Comment: The used keypad library doesn't use interrupts, so the problem must lie at another place. Please create a short working example, that shows your problem, so that we can see the whole code, that isn't working. That is better than cutting parts of the code out.

Comment: I've added the extra functions to make it (should be) working code. Lights fade in, lights blink, lights go solid colour. Hope that gives you more context.

Comment: In some cycles you iterate to `NUMPIXELS`. In some - to `strip.numPixels()`. Why the discrepancy? Are they the same?